# Angular with Firebase - missing or insufficient permissions after app check

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

I use [angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) to interact with firestore in my angular app. Unfortunately, after
I setup app check in the firebase console, I'm getting `ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` in the console of my webbrowser after the first interaction with firestore (see component below), Here are some useful informations for you, which I copied from my ticket in the angularfire repo.

#### Version info

**Angular:**

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.13
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.13
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.13
@schematics/angular             12.2.13
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5

**Firebase:**

9.19.0

**AngularFire:**

7.2.0

**Other (e.g. Ionic/Cordova, Node, browser, operating system):**

Node: 16.13.0

#### How to reproduce these conditions

In my component:

```
constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
this.firestore
        .collection('users')
        .snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe((documents) => {
          this.userDocuments = documents;
        })
```

**Steps to set up and reproduce**

I created a firebase web app under my project in the firebase console. In the app check tab, I paste the site secret from recaptcha into the required field, so it looks like this now:

[image: Screenshot 2021-11-29 at 17 02 42]

In my app.module.ts

```
imports: [
..
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    // // AppCheckModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    environment.useEmulators
      ? [AppCheckModule]
      : provideAppCheck(() => {
          const provider = new ReCaptchaV3Provider(environment.recaptcha);
          return initializeAppCheck(getApp(), {
            provider,
            isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
          });
        }),
  ],
```

In the `enviroment.ts`, I set the key from recaptcha. Furthermore the enviroment production key is set to true, so the `isDevMode()` returns false. There was the problem, that recaptcha is requiring a debug token otherwise.

**Sample data and security rules**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Debug output

`ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Can someone give me an advice how to proceed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppCheck for Firestore wasn't added until JS SDK 9.6 which was released couple of days ago. Its now working for me

See here:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

[image: screenshot]